# Check if string begins with one of several substrings in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, set

I couldn't figure out how to perform `line.startswith("substring")` for a set of substrings, so I tried a few variations on the code at bottom: since I have the luxury of known 4-character beginning substrings, but I'm pretty sure I've got the syntax wrong, since this doesn't reject any lines.

(Context: my aim is to throw out header lines when reading in a file. Header lines start with a limited set of strings, but I can't just check for the substring anywhere, because a valid content line may include a keyword later in the string.)

```
cleanLines = []
line = "sample input here"
if not line[0:3] in ["node", "path", "Path"]:  #skip standard headers
    cleanLines.append(line)
```

Comment: The ending index in string slicing is exclusive. You want `line[0:4]` or simply `line[:4]`

Comment: Annnnd that was all it took. Fixed. If you put that as an answer, I'll pick it at once.

Comment: If you do know how to do it using a length-insensitive startswith(), I'd be super grateful. I hate brittle hacks.

Comment: `.startswith()` calls the "beginning substrings" *prefixes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that string slicing is exclusive of the stop index:

```
In [7]: line = '0123456789'

In [8]: line[0:3]
Out[8]: '012'

In [9]: line[0:4]
Out[9]: '0123'

In [10]: line[:3]
Out[10]: '012'

In [11]: line[:4]
Out[11]: '0123'
```

Slicing a string between `i` and `j` returns the substring starting at `i`, and ending at (but not including) `j`.

Just to make your code run faster, you might want to test membership in sets, instead of in lists:

```
cleanLines = []
line = "sample input here"
blacklist = set(["node", "path", "Path"])
if line[:4] not in blacklist:  #skip standard headers
    cleanLines.append(line)
```

Now, what you're actually doing with that code is a `startswith`, which is not restricted by any length parameters:

```
In [12]: line = '0123456789'

In [13]: line.startswith('0')
Out[13]: True

In [14]: line.startswith('0123')
Out[14]: True

In [15]: line.startswith('03')
Out[15]: False
```

So you could do this to exclude headers:

```
cleanLines = []
line = "sample input here"
headers = ["node", "path", "Path"]
if not any(line.startswith(header) for header in headers) :  #skip standard headers
    cleanLines.append(line)
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `any(map(line.startswith, headers))` which I find cool.

Comment: Both the above and that in the answer are not necessary. [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) can also take a tuple of options, so it can be `if not line.startswith(tuple(headers)):`