# Python: How to filter out elements from an array of strings which are starting with a certain pattern

Tags: python

I have an array of Strings. I'd like to evict all elements which start with a pattern. The pattern is contained in another array.

```
words=[] # contains the word lists

banned_words = ["http:","https:","mailto:"]

for word in words:

    if (word.startswith(banned_words)):
        continue

    addWord(word)
```

I'm not including the addWord function for simplicity, however my attempt was to use the startsWith against the array of banned words. But it does not work. I could loop on each banned_words element and it will eventually work. However, is there a simpler approach to remove elements from an array whose string starts with (array) ?
Thanks

Comment: can you provide word list example

Comment: Just change to `word.startswith(tuple(banned_words))`...

Comment: `banned_words` is a list of strings, not a pattern. Don't say 'pattern' because that means 'regex'.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: that's the best answer, please post it as an answer. Most people aren't aware `.startswith(prefix, ...)` can take a tuple of strings.

Comment: @smci appreciate the offer, that is now part of the accepted answer anyway...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string begins with one of several substrings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573706/check-if-string-begins-with-one-of-several-substrings-in-python)

Comment: (@Tomerikoo: yes but that's a brutal duplicate question, since the OP's error is due to off-by-one string indexing, that question statement is too verbose, and the answers necessarily address that OP's indexing errors, not the spirit of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomerikoo has said

```
>>> help(str.startswith)
startswith(...)
    S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

    Return True if S starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
    With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
    With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
    prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

> "prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.". So it can also just be:

```
for word in words: 
    if word.startswith(tuple(banned_words))
```

Comment: Did you mean `word.startswith(pat)`?

Comment: *startswith only checks a single pattern* - that is not true... From the help that ***you*** provided: *"prefix can also be __a tuple of strings to try__."*. So it can also just be: `for word in words: if word.startswith(tuple(banned_words))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with a filter (more info [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension))

```py
final = [word for word in words if not any(word.startswith(t) for t in banned_words)]
```

Comment: You can remove the inner brackets (`[]`) and make the argument to `any` a generator comprehension.

Comment: Also you can use the `filter` function instead (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)). Note that the return type of `filter` is not a list.

Comment: I am more comprehension oriented but thank you.